# Android NumberPicker appending weird extra things to string array values for currently selected item

Tags: android, eclipse, numberpicker

I'm missing something obvious, I know.  So I have a number picker, 
tgt android 4.0.3, I wanted the higher numbers above the currently selected values -
so from the top of the screen to the bottom, the numbers are descending. 
So I populate a string array so that it's "200","195",..."20","15","10","5","0".
But here's the weird thing: when I select the 39th element, which is "5", what displays where it shows
the currently selected item becomes "55".  If I move off of that (so that I can see that element just
above or below what's currently selected) it goes back to being "5".

It also happens with "10" (becomes "105"), "15" (becomes "155"), and "20" (which, breaking the pattern, 
displays "200").  Anything above or below that displays normally (so "0" and "25" and so on).

If I have 10 elements, nothing happens, but as I add an 11th, the "5" starts showing "50".
If I have 20 elements, its the same, but as I add a 21st, the "5" starts showing "55", and the "10" starts showing "100"
And so on.

Here's the code

```
String[] values=new String[41];
            for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
                 values[values.length-1-i]=Integer.toString(i*5);
            }
NumberPicker npnow= (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.nowwarn_picker);

npnow.setMaxValue(values.length-1);
npnow.setMinValue(0);
npnow.setDisplayedValues(values);
npnow.setValue(35);

npnow.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
```

Also (in testing) if I set the string array like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    values[i]="i"+Integer.toString(200-i*5);
```

}

The problem is the same, but if I append the index before the value, like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    values[i]=Integer.toString(i)+Integer.toString(200-i*5);
}
```

The problem goes away.
When I show the current value via a toast in the onValueChanged listener, it toasts correctly but displays with the same problems.